# Membership service provider SignInManager SignInAsync is successful, however IsSignedIn is always false

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

I have seen other with a similar issue, but no answers seem to be correct.

I am able to register a user, it creates the user in my `SQL` database, however, after running the `"SignInAsync"` call, the user isnt signed in. See screen shots

Even after the next page loads, `IsSignedIn` is still `false` (and I can see that the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` session has been created when looking at developer tools)

[image]

Here is the session cookie:

[image]

Any suggestions? could I be missing a setup? (I have been following these videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egITMrwMOPU&t  (from part 65 to 70)

Comment: Do you have `app.UseAuthentication()` in your `Startup.Configure` (before other middleware)?

Comment: THANK YOU, I had "app.UseAuthorization();", i knew I missed something from the tutorials like that, but would have no idea where to start.... i did check and I even check the position of "app.UseAuthorization();"...  (Just checked the video where this is entered, and yep, he uses Authentication, not Authorization lol)